# Area defined with $\pm$ closedness

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, additive-combinatorics, geometric-measure-theory, convex-analysis

Denote $B_n\subset\Bbb R^n$ to be unit ball at origin.

Denote $S\subset B_n$ to region of type $\mathsf I$ if it satisfies
$$s\in S\iff\forall t\in S, s+t\in S\mbox{ or }s-t\in S$$

I am convinced $\mu(S)=0$ and likely is just a discrete set.

Denote $R\subset B_n$ to region of type $\mathsf{II}$ if it satisfies
$$s\in R\iff\forall t\in R, s+t\in  mB_n\mbox{ or }s-t\in mB_n$$

where $mB_n$ is unit ball scaled $m$ times where $m\in\Bbb R$.

Minimum $m$ needed so that $R=B_n$ is $\sqrt{2}$.

Among all such regions of type $\mathsf{II}$, what is $R$ with maximum volume with general $m\in[1,\sqrt{2}]$?

How many disjoint $R$ do you need to cover $p\%$ of $B_n$ when $m\in[1,\sqrt{2}]$?

Is there a simple geometric description such sets $R$ at least for those with maximum volume?

Comment: It seems to me that $B_n$ is of type $I$ so that is the answer to all your questions.

Comment: Not for $n>1$.  For example, if $N=2$, $s=(1,0)$, and $t=(0,1)$, neither $s+t$ nor $s-t$ is in the ball.  Actually, do you have an example of a set with positive volume that is type I?

Comment: I must be missing something here.  Suppose (just for simplicity) we're in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ is type $1$.  WLOG we can assume the furthest point from the origin in the set is of the form $(x,0)$.  Now consider the set of all $a$ such that $S$ has positive (one dimensional Lebesgue) measure along the line $x=a$.  If we take a near maximal (or near minimal) such $a$, then there must be two points whose sum isn't in $a$ (the set doesn't have positive measure along $x=2a$).  But the difference is on the $y$ axis, contradicting the type I property when combined with $(x,0)$'s maximal norm

Comment: @KevinP.Costello Perhaps there is no point at maximal distance from the origin?

Comment: Doesn't $\mu(S)=0$ follow immediately from the Brunn-Minkowksi inequality (replacing $S$ by $S\cup(-S)$ if necessary).

Comment: @ThomasBloom I do not know BM inequality. Does it?

Comment: It states that for measurable sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if $A+B$ is meausurable, then $\mu(A+B)^{1/n}\geq \mu(A)^{1/n}+\mu(B)^{1/n}$. In particular, if $A=-A=A-A$ then $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom No wonder I was getting nothing.